# Acrobat javascript for timesheet

Tags: javascript, acrobat

I'm way out of my element here and i've stubbed every toe at least twice stumbling around in the dark.

I have a timesheet form that runs Sun to Sat and looks kinda like:

```
    "Button to fill in dates for the week"
    Sun "Date field" In LunchOut LunchIn Out Total
    Mon "Date field" In LunchOut LunchIn Out Total
    .
    .
    .
    Sat
```

When I press the button I want it to fill in the correct dates for that week, regardless of when in the week i push it.  I've cobbled together some javascript snippits I found on the web, but I just don't have enough of framework to understand what I'm doing...but, oddly, I feel I'm on the right track, go figure.

Here's what I've got so far

```
    function fillDates(){
        var startDay = 0; //0=sunday, 1=monday etc.
    //    var d = now.getDay(); //get the current day
        var d = ("m/d/yy",new Date());
        var weekStart = new Date(now.valueOf() - (d<=0 ? 7-startDay:d-startDay*86400000); //rewind to start day
        var weekd1 = new Date(weekStart.valueOf() + 1*86400000); //add 1 days to get last day
        var weekd2 = new Date(weekStart.valueOf() + 2*86400000); //add 2 days to get last day
        var weekd3 = new Date(weekStart.valueOf() + 3*86400000); //add 3 days to get last day
        var weekd4 = new Date(weekStart.valueOf() + 4*86400000); //add 4 days to get last day
        var weekd5 = new Date(weekStart.valueOf() + 5*86400000); //add 5 days to get last day
        var weekEnd = new Date(weekStart.valueOf() + 6*86400000); //add 6 days to get last day
        this.getField("Sunday").value = weekStart

    //    var sun = this.getField("Sunday");
    //    sun.value = util.printd("m/d/yy",weekStart());
    //    var fld = this.getField("Monday");
    //    fld.value = util.printd("m/d/yy",new Date());
    }
    fillDates();
```

Acrobat first complained about "now" in "var d" now.getDay() declaration, so I changed it to that next line (no clue if that will work), then it complained about weekStart now.valueOf() and I'm not sure what that's refering to, didn't have and example and am out of time for the morning.  I'm getting the impression that acrobat's javascript may only have a subset of javascript stuff available and "now" isn't included...but that's a total guess.

Guidance?

Comment: Rob, if you had a suggestion it doesn't look like it posted successfully

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out...

```
var d = util.printd("dddd",new Date());
switch (d){
case "Sunday":
     d = 0;
     break;
case "Monday":
     d = 1;
     break;
case "Tuesday":
     d = 2;
     break;
case "Wednesday":
     d = 3;
     break;
case "Thursday":
     d = 4;
     break;
case "Friday":
     d = 5;
     break;
case "Saturday":
     d = 6;
     break;
}

var rightNow = new Date();
var msRightNow = rightNow.getTime();
var startDay = 0;
var rightNow = new Date();
var dMS = rightNow.getTime();
var weekStart = new Date(dMS - (d<=0 ? 7-startDay:d-startDay)*86400000);
var msWeekStart = weekStart.getTime();
var weekd2 = new Date(msWeekStart + 1*86400000); //add 1 days to get last day
var weekd3 = new Date(msWeekStart + 2*86400000); //add 2 days to get last day
var weekd4 = new Date(msWeekStart + 3*86400000); //add 3 days to get last day
var weekd5 = new Date(msWeekStart + 4*86400000); //add 4 days to get last day
var weekd6 = new Date(msWeekStart + 5*86400000); //add 5 days to get last day
var weekd7 = new Date(msWeekStart + 6*86400000); //add 6 days to get last day
var sunday = this.getField("Sunday");
sunday.value = util.printd("m/d/yy",weekStart);
var monday = this.getField("Monday");
monday.value = util.printd("m/d/yy",weekd2);
var tuesday = this.getField("Tuesday");
tuesday.value = util.printd("m/d/yy",weekd3);
var wednesday = this.getField("Wednesday");
wednesday.value = util.printd("m/d/yy",weekd4);
var thursday = this.getField("Thursday");
thursday.value = util.printd("m/d/yy",weekd5);
var friday = this.getField("Friday");
friday.value = util.printd("m/d/yy",weekd6);
var saturday = this.getField("Saturday");
saturday.value = util.printd("m/d/yy",weekd7);
```